# Come aggettivare Trump?

Tags: adjectives

Quale  aggettivo si può usare riferendosi a Donald Trump?

Abbiamo aggettivi come "[reganiano](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/R/reaganiano.php)" e "[kennediano](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=kennediano)", per cui sarà "trumpiano"?

Comment: Qualche esempio di “trumpiano” s'è già visto, ma temo che chiedere una previsione sia un po' impossibile (mutatis mutandis, nello SE sul Lego chiudono come off-topic le domande relative a modelli futuri ancora non annunciati). Anche i vocabolari più aggiornati riferiscono i neologismi dei mesi passati, non di quelli futuri. Ne riparliamo fra qualche mese, almeno?

Comment: Come non detto: nell'“osservatorio” della Treccani [già c'è](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?abcd=abdc&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/Gennaio_2016/trumpiano.xml&lettera=T), e da quasi un anno. Resta da vedere se si affermerà (anche se è probabile di sì).

Comment: @DaG: Potresti riportare quello che appare nell'"osservatorio della Treccani" come risposta?

Comment: Personalmente non la considero una risposta, @Charo. È una registrazione di una singola occorrenza del termine. Se questo aggettivo si affermerà, o se ce ne saranno altri, lo vedremo nei prossimi mesi.

Comment: @DaG - sembra essere più di un semplice caso:  https://www.google.it/search?q=trumpiano&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=trumpiano+&aqs=chrome..69i57.4294j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Curioso - è stato chiesto proprio ieri su SE anche per la lingua inglese: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109151/what-is-the-more-appropriate-adjectival-form-of-trump. Tra i suggerimenti anche "Trumptastic". o.O

Comment: @Federico Poloni - sì, l'idea mi è venuta da lì.

Comment: Giustissimo, @Gio, mi ero spiegato male: dicevo che non mi sembra che quella pagina della Treccani sia sufficiente per dare una risposta, perché *quella pagina*, senza darne un'analisi o altro, si limita a registrare una singola occorrenza di qualche tempo fa.

Comment: Beh, per esempio per Stalin abbiamo sia staliniano che stalinista, che in teoria dovrebbero distinguere "relativo a " e "seguace di" rispettivamente, ma nel tuo link su kennediano viene usato per entrambe le accezioni, mentre reganiano appare solo per la prima. Trumpista non suona "sbagliato" quindi magari vedremo la stessa distinzione?